# Expected jQuery({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1 }) to be '#container' doesnt work?

Tags: jquery, node.js, karma-runner

```
describe('Name validator',function () {



var elem;
beforeEach(function () {
   elem = $('<div id="container"><p>Hello World</p></div>');
});

it("allows us to seaarch with css",function () {
    expect(elem).toBe('#container');
});
```

});

I am re posting this questions to get some quick response.
Above given code is my test case and it gives the error

```
'Expected jQuery({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1 }) to be '#container'
```

Why is that? Any Solutions?